# Proving axioms type questions for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm really having trouble figuring out how to go about proving these statements.

I understand why they work and the logic but having trouble putting that on paper.

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $R$.

a) Show that for any $c$ $\in$ $F$ We have $c*0=0$

b) Show that for all $x\not= 0 $ $\in$ $V$ , if $c\not=0$, then $c*x\not= 0$.

c) Show that for all $x\not= 0 $ if $a\not=b$ then $a*x \not= b*x$.

EDIT: Going to write in what I tried putting down as suggested in comments:

a) If $c*0 = 0$

$c*0 = c*(0_1, 0_2, ... , 0_3) = (c*0_1, c*0_2, ... , c*0_n)$

$= (0_1, 0_2, ... , 0_n)$

$ = 0 $

b) For all $x\not=0\in V$, let $c\not=0$, then $c*x\not= 0$

because at least one of them must be 0 for their product to be 0.

c) Not sure how to start this one.

Comment: If you have trouble putting it on paper, how about you put it in the post. Doesn't matter if it is correct or complete. All that matters is that you give us some clue as to what you are having trouble with.

Comment: a) is fine. b) has the right idea, except you should really write it out in coordinates just as you did with a). Similarly with c), write it out in coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c) $a \neq b \implies a - b \neq 0$. Thus we have for $x \neq 0, (a - b)*x \neq 0$ (from part (b). $(a - b)*x \neq 0 \implies a*x \neq b*x$.